# How do I disable resampling in the SpriteKit framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

If I have a scene, let's say is 100x100. When I scale it up to the size of the phones screen, it gets all blurry, like MIP-Mapping. How can I make it so it is just pixelated when I scale up the scene?

Answer (score 1):

Change each affeced texture's filteringMode to nearest filtering. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKTexture/filteringMode

Comment: That will be an improvement, but the best results will come from point filtering to an integral multiple of the screen res, and then "linearly" filtering from there. Is that possible with SpriteKit?